# when making wpf the solution explorer has no folders or files

Tags: visual-studio

Every since I updated visual studio I'm no longer able to create or even view old wpf projects.

[screenshot of what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzEuh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing this by going into my system path and putting the 64 bit version of .NET above the 32 bit (x86) version.